# [FLUTTER][firebase_messaging] Error receiving background notifications for "Android 12" just when permissions are checked

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a bit desperate with an error when receiving push notifications in the background, and it is failing due to the error that I indicate below,

I was looking for possible solutions but I haven't found anything that worked, can you help me, maybe it's a bug in the firebase_messaging library? Has anyone experienced something similar?

#### **Devices & versions:**

- [FAIL] Physical Devide with Android 12: ***Fail***
- [✓] Physical Devide with Android 13: ***run perfect***
- [✓] Physical Devide with IOs 16.2: ***run perfect***

**NOTE**: I'm not sure if other versions prior to 12 get this error

#### **Flutter code where the error occurs:**

I have tried both possibilities with the same result:

`NotificationSettings settings = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();`

OR

`NotificationSettings settings = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getNotificationSettings();`

#### **Flutter Error:**

```
I/flutter (11341): FlutterFire Messaging: An error occurred in your background messaging handler:

I/flutter (11341): [firebase_messaging/unknown] Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

#### **Flutter environment:**

**plugins related and installed:**

- firebase_core: ^2.4.1
- firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
- flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
- permission_handler: ^10.2.0

**fllutter doctor -v**
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm64, locale es-ES)
• Flutter version 3.7.0 on channel stable at /Users/josevv/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision b06b8b2710 (hace 9 días), 2023-01-23 16:55:55 -0800
• Engine revision b24591ed32
• Dart version 2.19.0
• DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/josevv/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14C18
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.58.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• NE2213 (mobile) • eea79ab4 • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31)
• macOS (desktop) • macos    • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)    • chrome   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 109.0.5414.119

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!

Expected behavior: Receive background push notifications

current behavior: on android 12 (haven't been able to check on versions prior to 12), no background push notifications due to mentioned bug

Comment: Could you try `firebase_messaging: 14.1.1` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried several previous versions up to 14.0.1, but with the same problem.

In the end, how I have solved, it is not to use that line for Android and I simply use this sentence:

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
         .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
             AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!
         .requestPermission();
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
     NotificationSettings settings = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission( );
     if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {.....}
}

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I have solved it changing for Android (`NotificationSettings settings = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getNotificationSettings();` ) whit this simply piece of code, like this:

```
 if (Platform.isAndroid) {
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!
        .requestPermission();
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    NotificationSettings settings = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {.....}

}
```